# EasyMock: Times behaviour not being checked for strict mock

Tags: java, easymock

My unit test contains a "strict" mock of my DAO. My mocking behaviour is common to all tests apart from the @Test below. Therefore, I have added this common mocking behaviour within the @Before method. The specialist mocking behaviour is then added to the @Test itself:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    reset(myDAO);
    expect(myDAO.findMyObjects(code, myID)).andReturn(myObjects).times(1);
    expect(myDAO.findMyObjects(myID)).andReturn(myObjects).times(1);
    replay(myDAO);
}

@Test
public void testMyFirstMethod() {
    reset(myDAO);
    expect(myDAO.findMyObjects(myID)).andReturn(new ArrayList<MyObject>()).times(200);
    replay(myDAO);

    Set<OtherObject> otherObjects = myTestClass.myTestMethod(null, myID);
    assertEquals("Empty set is returned", 0, otherObjects.size());
}
```

I have checked that the .times(1) behaviour is validated in my other unit tests. However, in the above test the .times(200) behaviour is not validated (as my unit test only invokes this once).
Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `EasyMock.verify(myDAO)` to tell EasyMock that the replay is done and that the expectations should now be satisfied.

When you call `myTestMethod` only once, EasyMock doesn't know that it has to check `myDAO` before the method finishes, so it waits for more calls, and then the method returns successfully without EasyMock noticing that `findMyObjects` wasn't called enough times.

As for why the `times(1)` behavior is getting validated, I'm not sure, but I suspect that the verification might be triggered by other tests.

That said, your @Before method organization is really off.  You're setting expectations, starting a replay, resetting, and then replaying again?

Comment: OK so two questions: 1. Should verify be placed after my assertEquals? 2. How come I did not require a verify in my other tests, only this one?

Comment: `verify` should be placed after you've called all the methods on your mocked object that you expected to have been called.  (This can be before or after your `assertEquals.)
I have no idea why your other tests were working, although your `@Before` method seems to be more than a little confusing and mis-designed, which might be throwing all kinds of things off.

Comment: OK, thanks, why do you say mis-designed? I was including this behaviour in there as it's common to all other tests in my class.

Comment: It seems _very surprising_ for a `@Before` method to do something that's part of the testing itself.  I expect `@Before` methods to just initialize all the variables and the like, not to perform logic that's part of my tests.  It seems like a code smell that suggests that the tests should be reorganized some other way.

Comment: OK, thanks for advice. I've removed by @Before annotation and now I'm only invoking that mocking behaviour when I actually need it, as opposed to before each test. Perhaps, EasyMock does not like mocking being specified in Before or After methods as I was seeing some weird behaviour